# Color a region of a sphere bounded by a contour defined by discrete points

Tags: plotting

I have this programming problem: given a set of points on the unit sphere (which may not be evenly spaced, nor in the same plane but are extremely close and sequentially joining them forms a closed path), render in a different color the surface of the sphere divided by the closed path defined by those discrete points.

Test code snippet for arbitrary table `points`:

```
θ = 1;
points = Table[{Sin[θ] Cos[f], Sin[θ] Sin[f], Cos[θ]}, 
         {f, 0, 2 π, .1}];

Show[{Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], Lighter[Cyan], Specularity[White, 8], 
    Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> 1.2], ListPointPlot3D[points]}]
```

Comment: Can we assume that the points in question are *ordered*, so that the frontier will be p1-p2-...-pn-p1? Also, is each segment of the frontier a *geodesic* between two points? Can we assume that all the points lie in the same half-sphere?

Comment: @A.G. yes, the points are ordered and the curve does not cross itself. We cannot guarantee the points are in the same half-sphere. We can join each two neighbouring points via geodesic.

Comment: Your example data is too simplistic. Please supply a point set the is non-planar and unequally spaced, since that is what you require a solution to be able to handle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no well-posed question in this post; the OP is simply begging for somebody to act as a free coding service. He does not even offer a decent test case.

Answer (score 4):

First make a list of candidate points on the sphere:

```
spherepts = 
  Flatten[
    Table[{Cos[θ] Sin[φ], Sin[θ] Sin[φ], Cos[φ]},
    {θ, 0, 2 π, .05}, {φ, 0, π, .05}], 
   1];
```

Next, select from your list those points that are above the nearest point on the list of given `points` (i.e., the third component or z-value is larger):

```
shadedpts = 
  Select[spherepts, (# - First@Nearest[points, #])[[3]] > 0 &];
```

Then plot them:

```
Graphics3D[{fullgraphic, Red, Point[shadedpts]}]
```

where `fullgraphic` was defined by the poser.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But it does not work so well for me, maybe due to segmented points, e.g. `points = Table[
   If[f < \[Pi], {Sin[\[Pi]/2] Cos[f], Sin[\[Pi]/2] Sin[f], 
     Cos[\[Pi]/2]}, {Cos[f], 0, Sin[f]}], {f, 0, 2 \[Pi], .05}];` or `points = Table[
   If[f < \[Pi], {Sin[\[Pi]/2] Cos[f], Sin[\[Pi]/2] Sin[f], 
     Cos[\[Pi]/2]}, {Cos[-f], 0, Sin[-f]}], {f, 0, 2 \[Pi], .05}];` (real data much less predictable and have no analytic expressions)

Comment: A very awkward way to select your point.  If you're limiting yourself to $f < \pi$, why not simply put that restriction in the iterator?

Comment: f here still goes from 0 to 2 pi, just an example where the contour is made of two segments from 0<f<pi and pi<f<2pi

Comment: Your problem is that you have no unique way of stating whether a candidate point is "above" your contour, when such a point is above some point but beneath another (equally distant one).  You must craft a rigorous and unambiguous definition of the region for any code to work.  The current statement is ambiguous.  For instance you want to select points "above" the bottom arc, but really you want them to the left or the right.  Take a look at your boundary to see that ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks, I could be more clear on it; nevertheless, the points defines a closed curve and divide the sphere into two parts, let's call them A nd B. The coding problem is to color A and B differently.

Comment: One approach would be to perform a Riemann map of the boundary points on a sphere to a flat two-dimensional space, then use a Dilation operator in that space to color the "inside" of the boundary, then map those points back to the sphere.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SphericalPlot3D` with appropriate bounds and can apply different colors separately. Finally, use `Show` to combine them.

```
Show[{SphericalPlot3D[1, {phi, 0, ArcCos[Cos[1]]}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8], Red, Specularity[White, 8]], 
   Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}], 
  SphericalPlot3D[1, {phi, ArcCos[Cos[1]], Pi}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[Opacity[0.8], Lighter[Cyan], Specularity[White, 8]], 
   Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but the actual problem I have `points` only as numerical values, and I do not have analytical expression for the points. So I do not have a good way to specify the 'appropriate bounds' for `SphericalPlot3D`

Comment: Can't the points be translated to corresponding bounds in `theta` and `phi` using the parametric equations of sphere?

Comment: I do not know a good way to achieve that. `Interpolation[]` does not work since we can not guarantee the boundary f(x,y) is single-valued for a given (x,y).

Comment: The problem is for discrete points, which might be of an arbitrary contour.  In short, no—a simple parameterization is unrelated to the original question.